# redirect to secure connection thru .htaccess / exception admin location / framework Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, frameworks

I want to redirect http to https and in addition I have to remove admin location because it does not work with https. 
The site uses the Laravel framework.
At the code below I need to add the restriction:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second `RewriteCond` stops the rewrite from happening if it is the `/admin/` URI. The redirection is done using `R=301` which is a permanent redirection, for testing purposes I advise you change this to `R=302` as this is temporary.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: its not working because there is no admin folder - I don't understand framework Laravel

Comment: its easy to say - looks like is admin but still not working